# how do you access a variable in a firebase document in the security rules?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to do firebase security rules in firestore, and I want to allow users to write data to the "posts" collection if the current users id (request.auth.uid is equal to the "uid" in my "posts" collection.

Here is a picture of my firebase collection. I want to access the "uid" variable in the "posts" collection.[image]

Here is what I have so far in my security rules:
[image]

Thank you in advance! Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the current (pre-write) data of the document through `resource.data`, and the updates (post-write if the write is allowed) as `request.resource.data`.

So to access your UID field, that'd be `resource.data.uid` or `request.resource.data.uid` respectively.

For more on this, see the Firebase documentation on [data validation in security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation), on [fixing open access rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/insecure-rules#open_access), and on [restricting updates to certain fields](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-fields#restricting_fields_on_update).

Comment: Thanks so much Frank! Been trying to do that for way too long shoulda asked sooner haha.